# Oracle Regexp_replace

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to replace all the 'Spaces' with ' & ' excluding ' | ' in regexp_replace

For Ex: 'create | delete account' -> expect Output as 'create | delete & account'.

I m trying with the sql

```
select regexp_replace('create | delete account','\s [^\s\|\s]',' & ') from dual
```

But i m doing something wrong here. Could anyone please help on it.

Comment: If you have a sequence of spaces, do you need to replace every space with ' & '? Also, is it possible that you have the character '&' in your starting string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select regexp_replace('create | delete account', '([^\|]) ([^\|])', '\1 & \2')
from dual
```

The logic here is to make the replacement whenever a space should occur between two non pipe characters.  I capture these characters using parentheses, and then use them in the replacement via `\1` and `\2`.

Comment: Use `([^\|])\s+([^\|])` for the case of more than 3 spaces. +1 though.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Thanks for the comment and upvote :-)

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen -   Thank you .. It solved .. I liked the way you seen the requirement (ie) 'Replace space between two non pipe character'

Comment: This may work for the OP, but how about text like this: `'a | cos(b) exp(c) | z |\lambda|'`? The pipe symbol may appear with space on one side only, and that space SHOULD be replaced with `' & '` according to the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace every single space with the string `' & '`, and there's no `'&'` in your starting string, you may avoid regular expressions:

```
select replace ( replace('create | delete account', ' ', ' & '), ' & | & ', ' | ') from dual
```